# Count of retweets with tweepy with RESTful API?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

So I am doing fairly trivial task of retrieving tweets from a particular user. What I really want to do is to count how many times each of his tweets have been retweeted. I have looked at python's tweepy's API, and I have not been able to find a clear answer. Is there a way to do this in python?

Answer (score 0):

tweepy, might not have method for every endpoint in the twitter API.

tweepy should allow you to call an arbitrary endpoint, though.  When in doubt, you can check out the official twitter API to see what is offered.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1

It appears that you might only be able to get 100 retweets for a given tweet_id

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/retweets/%3Aid
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/retweeters/ids